# adding multiple nodes of cassandra DB in dbeaver client

Tags: cassandra, dbeaver

How can I add multiple nodes of cassandra DB in dbeaver client? The datastrax devcenter and it has functionality that can accept more than 1 node for a connection.  I need this in Dbeaver.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://dbeaver.com/databases/cassandra/ , in the example of how to create a connection, the connection setting window accepts more than one node in the `Host(s)` field, most likely it will accept a list of IP addresses of the nodes. Usually, these tools will connect to a node and from that node it will discover the characteristics of all the nodes in the cluster, which is maintained through constant gossip between the nodes.

Comment: I'm using 4.0.5 
and I don't want to upgrade